# How to deploy a standalone project that is based on OpenCV in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, opencv

I have a solution in VS 2010 that calls several OpenCV functions. Now I want to deploy (release) this project to use in another machine that doesn't have OpenCV. I don't want to install OpenCV on the other machine.

I know that I need several dll files, is there any automatic method that can collect all the desired files and put them together with the released .exe file so I can just send/copy this folder ?

Many thanks,

Answer (score 5):

If you have the solution in VS2010 you can look at the project Properties and check which OpenCV libraries the project is being linked with, and then ship those DLLs along with your application. It's a 2 min work.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response. Now even when I add the the dll files, an error "The application failed to initialize properly (0xc0150002). Click on OK to terminate the application." appear, and certainly the application doesn't run. Can you please advice ? thank you again

Comment: To what system are you trying to deploy? What Windows version? Which architecture are you compiling to and what's the target architecture?

Comment: Hello Karl. Both systems are windows xp 32 bit.

Comment: Hello Karl. I of course tried googling it for some days before posting the question. I couldn't really find a real "solid" procedure that tell you how to deploy your application in such a way that wraps all the required files in one folder, and this was my original question :)

Comment: You have to do this manually. Try using http://www.dependencywalker.com/ to assist on this task.

Comment: Thanks Karl. Perfect. So dependencywalker is the only way. When i tried dependencywalker before, it showed me many dependencies, so i was thinking if there is an easier way to bundle the files. But if that is the way then that's the way :).. Many thanks for your help.