# Package OpenCV Dll to distribute C++ DLL

Tags: c++, opencv, dll, software-distribution

I created on Visual Studio 2017 a DLL in C++ with a C wrapper and I am using the `OpenCV` library. I installed `OpenCV` on my computer, add the path of the `.lib` and `.dll` files in my project, and like this I am able to use my DLL in others programs. To be precise, I have now OpenCV on a folder `C:\opencv\...` and my visual studio solution on `C:\MG\DLL\MyDll.sln`.

But, in order to use it on another computer, I won't be able to install `OpenCV` so I have to find how to package the `OpenCV` library to distribute the correct files with my `.dll` file. Maybe I juste have to copy the `.dll` files of `OpenCV` in the same folder of my DLL ?

I don't know how to deal with this, because on internet I saw some people talking for example about `CMake`, others including some files in the project, ...

Moreover, I try to simulate this using a software in which I can add a C# plugin which use my C++ DLL. In this case, I rename the `OpenCV` folder to be sure the link with this folder is broken. If I copy the `.dll` files of `OpenCV`, the plugin is not functional anymore after renaming the installation folder of `OpenCV`.

Thank you in advance for sharing your experience/knowledge ;)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved my problem.

Copying the `.dll` files is not enough. **I needed to add to the PATH environment variable the folder where my DLL is with the software.**

Next step, do the same thing with my Python program with doesn't recognize the openCV dll when I rename the installation folder.

Comment: if you solve this problem by your self than just remove question form here, This place for asking and get a help from other not showing your knowledge on own question.

Comment: I can't because people answered me. It is why I add the solution and will close the topic tomorrow when I will be able to.

Comment: @KartikMaheshwari That's incorrect. Stack Overflow actively encourages users to answer their own questions. https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 3):

**All you need to do is copy the required OpenCV DLL files into your executable folder**

> Maybe I juste have to copy the .dll files of OpenCV in the same folder of my DLL ?

Yes, this is exactly all you need to do. You can even check in your development environment which DLLs you are linking to, those are the ones to copy across

[How to deploy a standalone project that is based on OpenCV in Visual Studio 2010?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7338052/how-to-deploy-a-standalone-project-that-is-based-on-opencv-in-visual-studio-2010)

Comment: Why visual needs to be linked to the `.lib`files of OpenCV so ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6957061/why-do-i-need-to-link-a-lib-file-to-my-project